# jQuery not detecting (almost) any event on some elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of pictures being pulled from the standard flickr API, and they all go in a list like this:

```
<div id="listImgFlickr">
    <div id="jflickrwrap">
        <div class="listImgs-box">
            <div class="listImgs">
                <p style="display: none"></p>
                <a class="thickbox" href="image.jpg" rel="index"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- rinse and repeat over and over -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and i have this jQuery script

```
jQuery("a").hover(function(){
        alert('maoe!');
})
```

the thing is: the script works for each and every link element on the page, except for the ones on the list. On the other hand, Thickbox is working fine, which means it can detect the links ok.

So, i've checked this:

- jQuery is being included only once
- the script that generates the list is on the header
- thickbox is on the footer
- test script above is also on the footer (after thickbox).
- I've also tested that script with `mouseover`, `mouseenter` and `click`, and setting it to `"p"`, `"a.thickbox"`,  `"img"` and still nothing.

Any clues?

Comment: do you have it inside a $(document).ready() handler?

Comment: Have you tried live function? Something like $("a").live("hover", function(){...});

Comment: are you loading these a elements with ajax? if so then you should use the live function as Alfonso said

Comment: Awesome, Alfonso and stratton, the live() did it. Can you move it to an answer so i can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're loading these elements with ajax you should use `.live()` instead of `hover()`
also, `.live()` has been deprecated as of 1.7 so depending on what jQuery version you use, consider using `.on()` instead. [more information here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 3):

You should use a delegation strategy. Attach the behavior to a container element that you know will be present when the page loads, like this:

```
$('#listImgFlickr').on('hover','a.thickbox', function(e){ // container?
   if( e.type === 'mouseenter' ) {
     alert('over!');
   } else {
     alert('out!');
   }
});
```

If `#listImgFlicker` is created dynamically, then you'd specify one of its parent elements.

Comment: +1   Don't use .live(). It's deprecated. Use .on() like in Ken's answer (this one)

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the action to "a" again if you add new "a" dynamically

Comment: but the "a"s are only generated once per page load, and before loading the other scripts... do i need to bind to it again?

Comment: The important thing is that you bind the action after all "a" you want to fire the event are present in the page